# How to filter email using firebase android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase. I want to search for some email ids using `orderbychild()` query. Please help me, I have posted my code below. This code returns value empty.

```
private void getFilterDataByEmail(String s) {
        mSearchProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        userLists.clear();
        final DatabaseReference usersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query;// = usersReference.child(ARG_USERS).orderByChild("username").startAt(s.toString());

        query = usersReference.child(ARG_USERS).orderByChild("email")
                .startAt(s.toString()).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                doTask(dataSnapshot, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                mSearchProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                suggestionListLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: This is my firebase database]

[image: This is my search box in the app]

[image]

The response I have got  is:
DataSnapshot { key = users, value = null }

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal snippet of the JSON you are trying to filter (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also: can you show the problem with a hard-coded value for `s`, so that we can rule out where you get that value from as a potential cause of problems?

Comment: hi, Frank van Puffelen! thanks for your reply. Actually my problem is to get the email ids which are in firebase database. I have a searchbox in my app, and i search the email ids in that box. for that I call the above function where "s" is the seach key.When i use orderByChild("username") instead of "email", I am getting the result correctly but email field is not retrieving anything. i dont want json response and all. i need to get the response directly from the firebase database using query listener as above code...please tell how to write how to fetch email using orderbychild("email").

Comment: @GraceVenkat what is ARG_USERS? Like Frank was asking, a text version of db would be better.

Comment: hi @Amruta-Pani , sorry for the inconvenience.The value for ARGS_USERS is "instacare_chat/users". thanks again

Comment: @GraceVenkat, the only case value returned null for me is when the query didnt match with any data in the db. The query string in your case is "su" which you need to make sure at least one such email beginning with "su" exists in db, which, at least, is not there in the part of data visible from the snapshot you shared.

Comment: hi @Amruta-Pani,I have added one more screenshot in the post, i was posted only the half of the db's screenshot. that's why it seems like that....but still i didnt get any result...thanks again.

Comment: @GraceVenkat int the second screenshot, what is the record below the pop-up that is showing no records found?

Comment: that is not relevant to this  issue. that is comes from the local storage